# Ordering friends

Tags: combinatorics

I have $n^2+1$ friends of different height and weight. Show that I can choose $n+1$ of them such that they are ordered both by height and weight (it doesn't matter if in decreasing or increasing order).

I've tried to use the pigeonhole principle...

Edited: I think the statement is clear now.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the problem. Does the problem say this. Let $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ have size $n^2+1$, then there exists a subset $T4$ of $S$ with size $n+1$ such that $T$ can be ordered by $<<$. (Where $(x_1,y_1)<<(x_2,y_2)$ iff $x_1\leq x_2$, $y_1\leq y_2$ )

Comment: If my guess is right, then the statment is false for $n=1$

Comment: Just making sure: the ordering needn't be ascending in both cases, does it?

Comment: I think this follows easily from the [Erdős–Szekeres theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Szekeres_theorem).

Comment: If the ordering can be different (i.e. height increases, weight decreases), this is just [Dilworth's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilworth%27s_theorem).

Answer (score 1):

This is an immediate consequence of the [Erdős–Szekeres theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Szekeres_theorem). Line them up in order of increasing weight. Let $h_1$ be the height of the first person in line, i.e., the lightest friend, $h_2$ the height of the second person in line, and so on up through $h_{n^2+1}$, the height of the heaviest friend. Now apply the Erdős–Szekeres theorem to the sequence $\langle h_1,h_2,\ldots,h_{n^2+1}\rangle$.